# ITextSharp repeat HTML table header in PDF

Tags: c#, html, itext

I have an HTML table in a view. I'm using ITextSharp 4 to convert the HTML to a PDF using the htmlParser. The table spans multiple pages. How do I get it to show the header on each page? Is there some setting I can turn on in HTML so that ITextSharp can recognise it?

Comment: Please, please use proper grammar and capitalization in your questions. It makes them easier to read, and less likely to be blocked by the quality filter.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have access to iTextSharp 4.0 but since the HTML parser writes directly to the document I'm not sure if it would be possible without modify the original source. Is it an option to upgrade to 5.0 which completely replaced the `HtmlParser` with a much more robust `HTMLWorker` object?

To have a `PdfPTable`'s headers span multiple page you need to set its `HeaderRows` property to the number of rows in your header. Unfortunately if you're using the `HTMLParser` or the `HTMLWorker` they do not currently treat `THEAD` and `TH` tags differently than `TBODY` and `TD` tags. The solution is to modify the `PdfPTable` sometime after parsing but before being written to the document. I don't have 4.0 available here but in 5.1.1.0 using the `HTMLWorker` you can easily do that and manually set the `HeaderRows` property:

```
        //Output file
        string outputFile = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Table.pdf");

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
        {
            using (Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER))
            {
                using (PdfWriter w = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs))
                {
                    doc.Open();

                    doc.NewPage();

                    //Create some long text to force a new page
                    string longText = String.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("Lorem ipsum.", 40));

                    //Create our table using both THEAD and TH which iTextSharp currently ignores
                    string html = "<table>";
                    html += "<thead><tr><th>Header Row 1/Cell 1</th><th>Header Row 1/Cell 2</th></tr><tr><th>Header Row 2/Cell 1</th><th>Header Row 2/Cell 2</th></tr></thead>";
                    html += "<tbody>";

                    for (int i = 3; i < 20; i++)
                    {
                        html += "<tr>";
                        html += String.Format("<td>Data Row {0}</td>", i);
                        html += String.Format("<td>{0}</td>", longText);
                        html += "</tr>";
                    }
                    html += "</tbody>";
                    html += "</table>";

                    using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(html))
                    {
                        //Get our list of elements (only 1 in this case)
                        List<IElement> elements = iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.ParseToList(sr, null);
                        foreach (IElement el in elements)
                        {
                            //If the element is a table manually set its header row count
                            if (el is PdfPTable)
                            {
                                ((PdfPTable)el).HeaderRows = 2;
                            }
                            doc.Add(el);
                        }
                    }
                    doc.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats useful. I'm using 4 as I don't want to make my source code freely available as is the requirement with 5 I believe? I'm looking to make my header repeat per page if there is more than one page, not exactly make the header span multiple rows...

Comment: I can't speak to your licensing concerns about 4 vs 5, but the code above will actually repeat the table header on every page. I just span'd it two rows to show a double-row header.

Comment: thank you Chris Haas. useful, but please tell me, how to use css using cssfile in iTextSharp with repeat header.

Answer (score 3):

you should just be able to set: table.HeaderRows = 1;

this will repeat the header on each page.

Answer (score 2):

Apply the "repeat-header" style, and set to "yes", like so:

```
<table style="repeat-header:yes;">
```